# Parsing a JSON object-within-an-object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
var json = {
        "cj-api": {
            "products": [
                {
                    "$": {
                        "total-matched": "231746",
                        "records-returned": "999",
                        "page-number": "1"
                    },
                    "product": [ {... // contains lots objects with the data I'd like to access } ]
```

As noted above, I want to access the `product` array of objects. I can't seem to do this though. I've tried:

```
console.log(json['cj-api']['products'][0]['product']);
```

But I get `typeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined`.

What's the correct way to access the array of `product` (note, singular `product`, not `products`). This data is coming from an external source so I can't alter the hyphen in `cj-api`.

EDIT: Here's what the raw console log of `json` looks like:

`{"cj-api":{"products":[{"$":{"total-matched":"231746","records-returned":"999","page-number":"1"},"product":[{ << lots of data in here>>`

EDIT 2: To further clarify, I got this object by running `JSON.stringify(result)` after I put some XML into [XML2js](https://npmjs.org/package/xml2js).

Comment: console.log(JSON['cj-api']['products'][0]['product']);

Comment: change your json spelling from console..

Comment: I notice in your console.log you use `json`, while you use `JSON` previously. I believe those are two different variables in javascript.

Comment: To all - I edited this as soon as I had posted it, this isn't the problem, just a spelling error when I wrote the question.

Comment: try `console.log(json)` and double-check if `json` is in fact defined and of the same structure at the point you are working with it.

Comment: i've tried your example. it's working here. so there must be something else, which isn't in your code snippet.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x7rRM/

Comment: @thriqon It does. I'll edit the un-beautified console log into the OP.

Comment: `typeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined` implies `json` is defined but `json['cj-api']` is not. Are you sure you're looking at the right thing?

Comment: @SalmanA When I `console.log(json)` I get: `{ 'cj-api': { products: [ [Object] ] } }`, I don't see a problem here but could be missing something.

Comment: Try `console.log(json, json["cj-api"], json["cj-api"]["products"])` (add items one by one).

Comment: @Jascination are you sure `json` is not a string?

Comment: @JanDvorak I used JSON.stringify on some XML data, I'm guessing this is my problem?

Comment: @Jascination if `json` is a string, you need to parse it first

Comment: Can you do `console.log(typeof json)`

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the following JSON structure:

```
var json = {
    "cj-api": {
        "products": [
            {
                "$": {
                    "total-matched": "231746",
                    "records-returned": "999",
                    "page-number": "1"
                },
                "product": [
                    {
                        "a": "a",
                        "b": "b",
                        "c": "c"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

with the log statement as:

```
console.log(json['cj-api']['products'][0]['product']);
```

And result is as follows:

**[Object { a="a", b="b", c="c"}]**

Comment: please see '[Are "works for me" answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)'

Comment: This is not an answer. Things like this (minus the example) are best left as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well your way of accessing json is absolutely correct. This is for debugging. Try

```
console.log(json['cj-api']);
console.log(json['cj-api']['products']);
console.log(json['cj-api']['products'][0]);
console.log(json['cj-api']['products'][0]['product']);
```

Which ever line returns `undefined` means your json is broken there.

If this doesn't work then you need to check for other similar keys. Maybe they value you are trying to find is **actually** `undefined`.

Maybe you are trying to loop. If you are then check for the condition `if (JSONStructure[key]==undefined) console.log("Undefined at position ...")`. That is the only way *if* you have valid JSON.

Comment: from the OP's question: `typeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined` so `json["cj-api"]` is already `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`typeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined` means that `json` exists, but `json['cj-api']` is undefined. If you are sure that you are using the right variable name, I think this might be a scope issue, where you are using an other variable than you intend to. `json` might be the json string, instead of the array-like object. Try renaming your variable and see if you still get this problem. Otherwise the string is not automatically parsed for you and you'll have to parse it with `JSON.parse( ... )`.

---

Edit:

```
var json = '{ "me": "be an evil string" }';
console.log( json ); //'{ "me": "be an evil string" }'
console.log( json['me'] ); //undefined

console.log( JSON.parse( json )['me'] ); // 'be an evil string'
```

Comment: shouldn't the last line be either `console.log (JSON.parse(json)["me"]) //...` or `... //Object { "me": "be an evil string" }`

Comment: =) Oh, i didn't see the edit, the evil clipboard being the culprit again, it's playing the same game with me too from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is missing the last

```
}
        ]
    }
}
```

and others here changed your example and made it work, did you try to correct it?

If not then I suggest you or the dataprovider correct the structure of the reply.

Comment: My understanding is that `"product": [ {...`  *(the ...)* indicates the missing part is intentionally not included in the question, but exists in the real code

Comment: I tought so too at first, but as I ran into the same situation as two other posters it seemed to me the error was in the data sooner than in the OP code. I guess i could have asked if the Product list validated too.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried below json structure

```
var json={
    "cj-api": {
        "products": [
            {
                "$": {
                    "total-matched": "231746",
                    "records-returned": "999",
                    "page-number": "1"
                },
                "product": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

now `json['cj-api']['products'][0]['product']` will work

Comment: I can't see any difference between this and the asker's object

Comment: i have posted what i tried.. please remove downvoting..give respect to people who tried something..try to convert the json string to json object

Comment: @Amith while we appreciate effort, answers are rated based on correctness and completeness, not how long they took to write.